# need help pushing with github

Tags: git, github

I finished a tutorial on how to make a to-do list with JavaScript and html. It's in a folder that contains two files one in html and another in JavaScript. I got into that path for that folder and did `git push -u origin master` and it pushed up a rails app instead.

Do I need to reset git someone so I can have it push what I want it to?

when I did git log this is what I got kind of confusing

```
C:\Users\Marshall\Project\rails_projects\todolist>git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       deleted:    .gitignore                                                  
#       deleted:    Gemfile                                                     
#       deleted:    Gemfile.lock                                                
#       deleted:    README.rdoc                                                 
#       deleted:    REDME.md                                                    
#       deleted:    Rakefile                                                    
#       deleted:    app/assets/images/.keep                                     
#       deleted:    app/assets/javascripts/application.js                       
#       deleted:    app/assets/javascripts/funtimes.js.coffee                   
#       deleted:    app/assets/stylesheets/application.css                      
#       deleted:    app/assets/stylesheets/funtimes.css.scss                    
#       deleted:    app/controllers/application_controller.rb                   
#       deleted:    app/controllers/concerns/.keep                              
#       deleted:    app/controllers/funtimes_controller.rb                      
#       deleted:    app/helpers/application_helper.rb                           
#       deleted:    app/helpers/funtimes_helper.rb                              
#       deleted:    app/mailers/.keep                                           
#       deleted:    app/models/.keep                                            
#       deleted:    app/models/concerns/.keep                                   
#       deleted:    app/views/funtimes/index.html.erb                           
#       deleted:    app/views/layouts/application.html.erb                      
#       deleted:    bin/bundle                                                  
#       deleted:    bin/rails                                                   
#       deleted:    bin/rake                                                    
#       deleted:    config.ru                                                   
#       deleted:    config/application.rb                                       
#       deleted:    config/boot.rb                                              
#       deleted:    config/database.yml                                         
#       deleted:    config/environment.rb                                       
#       deleted:    config/environments/development.rb                          
#       deleted:    config/environments/production.rb                           
#       deleted:    config/environments/test.rb                                 
#       deleted:    config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb                  
#       deleted:    config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb             
#       deleted:    config/initializers/inflections.rb                          
#       deleted:    config/initializers/mime_types.rb                           
#       deleted:    config/initializers/secret_token.rb                         
#       deleted:    config/initializers/session_store.rb                        
#       deleted:    config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb                      
#       deleted:    config/locales/en.yml                                       
#       deleted:    config/routes.rb                                            
#       deleted:    db/seeds.rb                                                 
#       deleted:    lib/assets/.keep                                            
#       deleted:    lib/tasks/.keep                                             
#       deleted:    log/.keep                                                   
#       deleted:    public/404.html                                             
#       deleted:    public/422.html                                             
#       deleted:    public/500.html                                             
#       deleted:    public/favicon.ico                                          
#       deleted:    public/robots.txt                                           
#       deleted:    test/controllers/.keep                                      
#       deleted:    test/controllers/funtimes_controller_test.rb                
#       deleted:    test/fixtures/.keep                                         
#       deleted:    test/helpers/.keep                                          
#       deleted:    test/helpers/funtimes_helper_test.rb                        
#       deleted:    test/integration/.keep                                      
#       deleted:    test/mailers/.keep                                          
#       deleted:    test/models/.keep                                           
#       deleted:    test/test_helper.rb                                         
#       deleted:    vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep                             
#       deleted:    vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep                             #                                                                               
# Untracked files:                                                              
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)              #                                                                               
#       todo.html                                                               
#       todo.js                                                                 
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: please add a link to the tutorial you were following. what is the output of `git remote -v`? looks like you cloned some rails project deleted everything and replaced it by your two files.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty self-explanatory. You should first stage changed files and commit them.

```
git add .
git commit -m "something"
```

Then push to remote

Answer (score 0):

did you run

```
git add .
```

before these commands

```
git commit -a -m "your commit message"
git push origin master
```

?